# getting jquery fields from a List

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, jquery-pagination

In the below jsp code the fields are hard code but can i get the fields by using loop from a list which may grow dynamically

```
  List list=[userid,firstname,lastname,email];
```

for every new request this list may grow or shrink dynamically depends on the columns of the table present in database ,so is there any way to get the field name without hard coding..

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
    <link href="css/metro/crimson/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Include jTable script file. -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of people',
                paging: true, //Enable paging
                pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)           
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'CRUDController?action=list',
                    createAction:'CRUDController?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'CRUDController?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'CRUDController?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    userid: {
                        title:'S.NO',
                        key: true,
                        list: true,
                        create:true
                    },
                    firstName: {
                        title: 'First Name',
                        width: '30%',
                        edit:false
                    },
                    lastName: {
                        title: 'Last Name',
                        width: '30%',
                        edit:true
                    },
                    email: {
                        title: 'Email',
                        width: '20%',
                        edit: true
                    }                
                }
            });
            $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width:60%;margin-right:20%;margin-left:20%;text-align:center;">
    <div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved by iterating over a list

```
<%
    HttpSession sec = request.getSession();
  List<String> columnsList=(List<String>)sec.getAttribute("columnsList");
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
var jsArray = [<%for (int i = 0; i < columnsList.size(); i++) {%>"<%=columnsList.get(i)%>"<%=i + 1 < columnsList.size() ? ",":""%><%}%>];

var fields={};
var arrayLength = jsArray.length;

for(var i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)
    {
fields[jsArray[i]] = {
    title: jsArray[i],
   width: '40%',


};
}

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'Table of people',
            paging : true, //Enable paging
            sorting: true, //Enable sorting
            defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
            pageSize : 10, //Set page size (default: 10)  


            actions : {
                listAction : 'DATA?action=list'

            },
            fields : fields
});


    //Load all records when page is first shown
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');


});

</script>
```